# peoplePickerNavigationController catch the click of the actual contact name

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbookui

I am trying to catch the click of the contact name, and grab the contact info from there.  Instead of clicking into the contact's info and clicking a field from there.

I am able to grab all data needed, but only after clicking into the contact.  Here is my current code:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
        shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
        property:(ABPropertyID)property 
        identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    [self displayPerson:person];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return YES;
}

-(void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSString *name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);

    NSString *phone = nil;

    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {

        phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)

        ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);

    } else {

        phone = @"[None]";

    }

    NSLog(@"Phone: %@", phone);
}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply return `NO` in `shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson`.

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007079):

> Return Value:
>   YES to display the contact and dismiss the picker.
>   NO to do nothing.

So by returning `NO` you skip the display step. You are dismissing the picker yourself anyway.

Comment: I've tried that and no change.  It still doesn't dismiss until after I click the email field (for example).

Answer (score 0):

I was using:

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier;
```

But, when I used the following it works just fine.  That drove me nuts.  lol

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person;
```